# Attempting to test an embedded nand flash chip by filling up a file to drive capacity

Tags: bash, dd, busybox

I'm trying to test an embedded nand flash chip using the dd command (write random data to a file):

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/nand/storage/testnand/test.raw bs=100000 count=50 2> /dev/null
```

However, the unit I'm testing is running busybox v1, and it has been patched. The dd command is not recognized. Is there an alternative command that will help me achieve the same results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
head -c $((100000*50)) /dev/urandom > test.raw
```

will save 100000 * 50 = 5000000 bytes, combining Bash's [Arithmetic expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) and head's `-c number_of_bytes` parameter.

For debugging: expanding on allquixotic's idea, this command prints "$i done" at 1000, 2000, etc.

```
{ for i in {1..100000}; do echo $i; if (( ($i % 1000) == 0 )); then echo "$i done" 1>&2; fi; done } > test.raw
```

Comment: Ooh nice! :) Didn't think of generating data with `head`...

Comment: @ignis - If I wanted this script to continue until there is an error or the user stops, would I need to add /dev/null back?

Comment: @suffa The user can stop with Ctrl+C, and I believe the command will stop automatically if there's an error. `2>/dev/null` merely hides the error messages, in no way it will influence the command itself.

Comment: @ignis - keep getting a syntax error on the debugging section you added recently.

Comment: @suffa I do not get errors, on Bash 4.2.37(1) / Ubuntu 12.10, Bash 4.2.45(2) / Arch Linux 2013.04, Bash 4.2.39(1) / Fedora 18. Does `echo $0` return "bash"? If so, what version does `bash --version` print?

Comment: @ignis - I will make sure I didn't make any typos. ... on BusyBox v1.10.2-uc0 ... built-in shell (msh)

Comment: @suffa Please try `for i in $(seq 1 100000); do echo $i; if (( ($i % 1000) == 0 )); then echo "$i done" 1>&2; fi; done > test.raw` but I won't be able to help if it does not work, because different shells have slightly different syntaxes, and because I do not know msh. The links I gave in the comments are for Bash. Please retag the question as msh, to increase the probability that someone that knows that shell bumps into the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can try

- `cat /dev/urandom > /nand/storage/testnand/test.raw`
- `for i in $(seq 1 10000000); do echo $i >> /nand/storage/testnand/test.raw; done`

I can't think of much else that would work if you don't even have `dd` or `cat`...

Comment: Expanding on your idea, I'd do `{ for i in {1..100000}; do echo $i; done } > test.raw` which opens test.raw only 1 time

Comment: @ignis does the ellipsis in your comment account for: {1 seq 10000000}?

Comment: @suffa Nope, it's an alternative syntax for `seq 1 100000`, documented [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Loops_.28while.2C_until_and_for.29) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)